# jQuery - Get CSS value from element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am searching a container to grab the padding of a matched element like this..

```js
padding = $( ".container" ).find( ".set_height" ).css( "padding-top" );

console.log(padding);
```

```css
.set_height {
    padding-top:50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">

 <div class="section">
  <div class="match_height">
      Section 1
  </div>
 </div>

 <div class="section">
  <div class="match_height">
      Section 2
  </div>
 </div>

 <div class="section">
  <div class="set_height">
     Section 3
  </div>
 </div>

</div>
```

The `set_height` div could also potentially be `fixed_height` or `dynamic_height`

How can I modify the jQuery to search for one of those and stop when it finds one, so if there are multiples then it will just grab the value for the first one it finds?

Comment: you can do this 
`.find( ".set_height, .fixed_height, .dynamic_height" ).first()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/

You can pass a list of classes as a selector.

```
var padding = 0;
var items = $( ".container" ).find( ".set_height, .fixed_height, .dynamic_height");
if (items.length) {
    padding = items[0].style.paddingTop; 
}
```

---

#### EDIT

@segu is right (thanks), but it's not sufficient to just call `first()`, you have to check if the result of `first().style` is `undefined`, because calling `first().style.paddingTop` can trigger `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'paddingTop' of undefined` if no results are found. I just used `length` property instead.

Comment: You should use .first() instead of [0] because you will prevent unexpected behavour errors.

Comment: Can not get [0] of undefined. You have the possibility of not  found any element with selectors

Comment: returns undefined. The other implementation can return errors

You have jsfiddle  here with examples https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/931724/ @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs

The problem of this solution is that he's mixing js dom properties with jquery. If you are using jquery, you should profit all methods from jquery for avoid errors.

Comment: @segu ahh I see, dankes for explaining :) will rm my comments :)

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs no problem, just explaining a better approach of using jquery

Comment: Thanks everyone, explains things great!